# Multiple Framer Motion refs per react component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, framer-motion

I am using Framer Motion to create animations on my react web app.

Specifically, scroll-tied animation, where the progress of the animation is directly associated with the progress of the scroll down the page.

To do this I have used code like in the following example react component:

```
const App = () => {
  const targetRef = useRef(null);
  const {scrollYProgress} = useScroll({
    target: targetRef,
    offset: ["start 0.1", "start 0.05"] //target container
  });

  const heroColour = "white";
  const color = useTransform(scrollYProgress, [0, 1], ["#FFFFFF", "#333333"])
  return (
    <div className="App">
      < Hero colour={heroColour} />
      <div ref={targetRef}>
        < Main />
      </div>
      <div ref={targetRef2}>
        < Header colour={color} />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

This works, however, I cannot figure out how I would create another animation with a different targetRef (e.g. targetRef2) given scrollYProgress cannot change.

Does anyone know how I would do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can rename the destructuring of each individual `useScroll` hook. For example:

```
const targetRef1 = useRef(null);

const targetRef2 = useRef(null);

const {scrollYProgress: scrollYProgressTarget1} = useScroll({
  target: targetRef1,
  offset: ["start 0.1", "start 0.05"]
});

const {scrollYProgress: scrollYProgressTarget2} = useScroll({
  target: targetRef2,
  offset: ["start 0.1", "start 0.05"]
});
```

This way you can use them separately.